# Bootstrap container arrangement

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web

I need some help, how can I put containers like this? [Click here for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdolt.png)

I've tried everything but I cant do it.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Comment: Please show us your best try. Add it to your question by using [Edit].

Comment: Read the Bootstrap Grid System section of their docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the subject line, I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap.  [Here is some more information on containers.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/)

If you're not using Bootstrap, you can simply go into your CSS file and change width, height, & display properties like I did below.

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"></div>
```

Of course, there are many other ways of doing this and I encourage you to further your reading of various documentation.